# Uneditable calendar events in O365 using graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm importing lots of events into calendar in a calendar group in Office 365 on behalf of the user. These events shouldn't be editable by the user because I may overwrite changes that they make with further updates to these events. When using the graph API and retrieving an event I get told if the current user is able to edit the event through the `canEdit` property. Very similar to how an imported iCal file is shown to the user in O365, but the user can't change any of the events.

Is it possible to mark a set of events as un-editable by the user through the UI using the graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to disable changing an event in the user's calendar. They own access to the events on their calendar. You may need to cache the changekey of events added to the calendar to later determine if an event has changed.